# Autoplay of YouTube using iframe not working in android and iphones

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, youtube

I am using jquery to load YouTube Video through iframe to reduce the initial page load time. Using this approach – only the video thumbnail is loaded along with the page and the actual player loads when the user hits the play button. But AutoPlay is not working on Android and Iphones though it is perfectly working on desktops using windows. When I googled this problem, it turns out "Chrome and Safari browsers on iPhone and Android only allow playback of HTML5 video when initiated by a user interaction. They block embedded media from automatic playback to prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks." I want to autoplay the video. Please help.

Here is my jquery

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function() {
        var div, n,
            v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
        for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
            div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
            div.innerHTML = YouTubeThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
            div.onclick = YouTubeIframe;
            v[n].appendChild(div);
        }
    });

function YouTubeThumb(id) {
    var thumb = '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/mqdefault.jpg">',
        play = '<div class="play"></div>';
    return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
}

function YouTubeIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1";
    iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", this.dataset.id));
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="YouTube_Video_ID"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this example:-

```
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an  (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I want to upload only video thumbnail along with the page and the actual player to be loaded when the user hits the play button so that I can differ parsing of javascript of YouTube to increase page load speed.